# jQuery select image in div if image parent does't have a certain class

Tags: jquery-selectors

Wordpress wraps images with captions in a div with a class of .wp-caption. 
I'm looking for a way to select images that don't have this div so I can wrap them in different div. (to keep a consistent border around all the images)

```
<div class="blog-post-content"> 
 <div id="attachment_220" class="wp-caption alignleft" style="width: 310px">
  <a href="/somewhere/"><img class="size-medium wp-image-220" src="/path/to/image" alt="" width="300" height="280" /></a>
  <p class="wp-caption-text">Caption Text</p>
 </div>
 <p>This is the body of the post</p>
</div>
```

To test my selector, I'm just trying to add a green border. I can handle the .wrap() once the selector is working.

The most promising of my attempts is:

```
$('.blog-post-content img').parent('div:not(".wp-caption")').css('border', '2px solid green');
```

... but no luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this: (untested)

```
$('.blog-post-content img').filter(function(){
    return !$(this).parents('div').hasClass('wp-caption');
}).css('border', '2px solid green');
```

Comment: You'll need parents() instead of parent() because there seems to be an extra element (an a) between the img and the div. Otherwise seems fine. Edit: Infact you could just use return !$(this).parents('div.wp-caption').length;, but that's just nitpicking.

Comment: This works great whether or not the image is used in a link. I was NOWHERE near this when I was working though it. Thanks a lot. Stackoverflow rocks.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$('.blog-post-content img').parent(':not("div.wp-caption")')
```

Not if what Matti says abotu the `a` element in the hierarchy then the above wont work.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question was asked a long time ago, but I would like to suggest the following:

```
$('.blog-post-content img').closest('div:not(".wp-caption")')
```

Untested, but I think that should work, and is shorter than the answer above that works. Using closest means the a is ignored.